# findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation with GMSPlaceField.addressComponents fails

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

Migrating to the new iOS Google Places SDK v3.0.2 as required by Google as of Jan 29th, 2019. Requesting a location for the current user location. This is what I am currently calling which matches up with the recommendation in the docs.

```
let fields: GMSPlaceField = GMSPlaceField(rawValue:
   UInt(GMSPlaceField.name.rawValue) | 
   UInt(GMSPlaceField.addressComponents.rawValue))!

self.findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation(
   withPlaceFields: 
   fields, callback: callback)
```

I pass in a `GMSPlaceLikelihoodsCallback` for the callback I am calling. The result of the call is an error -

An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/support)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/support).

Error Domain=com.google.places.api.server.ErrorDomain Code=-2 "Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'address_components'. " UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error while parsing 'fields' parameter: Unsupported field name 'address_components'.

`GMSPlaceField.addressComponents` is not listed on the documentation as an unsupported field for this API call. Is there anything to be done but file the bug that is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Google responded to my bug post that this is an internal issue and a fix will be issued shortly.

**EDIT**

Apparently this is currently intended behavior and the solution is to make two API requests instead. One to `findPlaceLikelihoodsFromCurrentLocation` and another to `fetchPlaceFromPlaceID` the first returning place ids and the second requesting the actual address information.